# How to get a block code from soapUI xml response and inject as request body?

Tags: java, groovy, automation, soapui

I have a soap ui response as below.

```
<Quantity>
<item id="0001" type="donut">
    <name>Cake</name>
    <ppu>0.55</ppu>
    <batters>
        <batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
        <batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
        <batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>
    </batters>
    <topping id="5001">None</topping>
    <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
    <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
    <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
    <topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
    <topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
</item>
</Quantity>
```

Now I need to get all the data from `<batters>...</batters>` using soap ui groovy script and Send replace in a request body to other test. Say I have:

```
<Total>
<section id="0001" type="donut">
    <name>Cake</name>
    <ppu>0.55</ppu>
    <batters>
        <batter id="3333">Regular</batter>
        <batter id="4444">Chocolate</batter>
        <batter id="5555">Blueberry</batter>
    </batters>
    <topping id="5001">None</topping>
    <topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
    <topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
    <topping id="5006">Sprinkles</topping>
    <topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
    <topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
</Section>
```

I would like to replace the `<batters>...</batters>` section with the response from previous.

Or could you tell me how to get the block code between `<batters>....</batters>`

Comment: But there seemed to be a repeating `item`, how would you want it to address?

Comment: @Rao there is no repeating item. It will occur only once. Let me update the question

Comment: Thank you for the edit. What is 2nd request type? rest or soap? Looks `id` did not match, not to bother? Only looking for `batter` value?

Comment: @Rao yes. I am just looking to get the batter block into the request body